# How do I run one function after another one in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code, I have `loadData()` and `useFilter()`. I tried to run `loadData()` first as `productsData` need to be set for `useFilter()` to process `productsData`. However, I tried `.then()` but it still gives me `undefined` when I console log `useFilter()` How do I fix this?

```
  const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState(null);

  const loadData = async () => {
    const { data } = await getAxios().get('/market/list').then(response => response.data)
    setProductsData(data)
  }

  const useFilter = () => {
    return productsData.map(data => (...))
    //filters productsData
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    loadData().then(()=>useFilter());
  },[])
```

Comment: Return the new data from loadData, or have useFilter be an effect with productData in its deps.

Comment: Your `useFilter` function that is inside the useEffect has a reference to the initial `productsData` object (and that is null).

Answer (score 0):

Changing state **asynchronous**. So using state immediately after changing that may not be updated one.

You can use `useEffect` to call your function after state changed.

You can do this:

```
const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState(null);

const useFilter = () => {
  return productsData.map(data => (...))
  //filters productsData
};

useEffect(()=>{
  const loadData = async () => {
    const { data } = await getAxios().get('/market/list').then(response => response.data)
    setProductsData(data)
  }
  loadData()
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
  useFilter();
},[productsData])
```

Comment: This works but it does not explain why the implementation given does not work

Comment: @Yash.S.Narang I updated my answer. If you need more information, just tell me to explain more.

Comment: I meant he wants an asynchronous implementation and you are suggesting a different implementation

Comment: Sure No problem we can let him decide what he wants to implement

Answer (score 0):

Hello just by making a function async doesn't make it return a promise in order to use .then on function calls you must make sure they return promises

So one implementation you could do is :

```
    const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState(null);

  const loadData = () => {
    return getAxios().get('/market/list').then(response => response.data)
  }

  const useFilter = () => {
    return productsData.map(data => (...))
    //filters productsData
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    loadData().then((data)=>{
    setProductsData(data);
    useFilter();
    }
   );
  },[])
```

In the above implementation I return the promise that axios returns you can also return your own promise by creating a promise using new Promise() constructor

Do let me know if you face any issues